# Good zip code+4 is not validating with jQuery and regex

Tags: jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm using jQuery to validate form elements on an MVC form and this is my regular expression to validate zip codes:

```
^(\d{5})|(\d{5}-\d{4})$
```

It validates a 5-digit zip code just fine, but the red box around the text box input element remains—er, comes back—when I add a hyphen and 4 more digits.

Why?

Comment: Perhaps the error is in another part of your code?

Comment: Seems odd that it would validate the first 5 digits perfectly then, doesn't it?

Comment: Could not reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/RNvZM/

Comment: If you're using jQuery Validate, there's already a rule for that called `zipcodeUS`; you simply need to include the `additional-methods.js` file.  Otherwise, you can just pull the `zipcodeUS` regex out of that.

Comment: Rolled back the last edit.  Please post your solution as an answer below and "accept" your own answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I looked more closely at the generated HTML, I noticed that it has data-val-length-max="9". This is an attribute in the model. I changed it to 10, and voilà!

To allow the validation to work properly and still pass the unformatted digits to the database, I just return this from the getter of the model:

```
_zip.Replace("-", string.Empty)
```

Answer (score 4):

The brackets are wrong in the following RegRxp:

```
^(\d{5})|(\d{5}-\d{4})$
```

This iIs like saying match `^\d\d\d\d\d` or match `\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d$`. It incorrectly matches `12345x` and `x98765-4321`. Use the following instead:

```
^(\d{5}|\d{5}-\d{4})$
```

Comment: This is a great catch. I got the original regex from MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx). However, their sample was missing the closing parenthesis (which I added). The result of their incorrect regex, however, was greater leniency (i.e., it allowed MORE inputs to pass muster). My form is still rejecting the 5+4 zip codes.

Comment: Added the answer in the original question. Still, thanks for the regex catch, Salman.

Comment: @birdus, please don't put your solution in the question.  Please post another answer yourself and "accept" that instead.